# Fish Shell - Virtualenv path not prepended to PATH

Tags: shell, path, fish

I am on a Mac running macOS Mojave. I run Iterm2 for terminal and fish version 3.0.0. I also use pipenv to manage my local development.

I have this problem where when I activate a python virtual env, via `>pipenv shell`, the virtual env path is slotted into the middle of the PATH list after the `/usr/local/bin` which on a Mac is where Homebrew installs binaries. Therefore also the virtual env is activated when I type `>which python`, I get the python from the system and not the virtual env as I would expect.

**Example**

**Path before virtual env activation with pipenv shell command**

`PATH=/Users/napo/bin:/Users/napo/.local/bin:/Users/napo/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin`

**Path after virtual env activation with pipenv shell command**

`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Users/napo/.local/share/virtualenvs/learn-gXU4lJPg/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26/libexec/tools:/Users/napo/bin:/Users/napo/.local/bin:/Users/napo/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin`

Apart from the problem with duplicates of paths entries, one can see that `/Users/napo/.local/share/virtualenvs/learn-gXU4lJPg/bin` has been slotted somewhere in the middle of that list.

I'll be most grateful for a fix. Below is my current full **config.fish**

```
if status --is-login
    # Homebrew
    set -x HOMEBREW_INSTALL_CLEANUP 1

    # Golang
    set -gx GOPATH ~/go/

    # Don't write bytecode, Python!
    set -x PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
    set -x PIPENV_SHELL_FANCY 1
    set -x PIPENV_MAX_SUBPROCESS 64
    set -x EDITOR nvim

    set -gx OSTYPE macOS
    set -gx WORKON_HOME /Users/napo/.local/share/virtualenvs

    # android sdk
    set -gx ANDROID_NDK_HOME /usr/local/share/android-ndk
    set -gx ANDROID_SDK_ROOT /usr/local/share/android-sdk

    # Make fzf respect .gitignore using fd command

    set -gx FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND 'rg --files'

    # Now fzf (w/o pipe) will use fd instead of find
    # To apply the command to CTRL-T as well
    set -gx FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND

    set -gx VIMCONFIG ~/.config/nvim
    set -gx VIMDATA ~/.local/share/nvim
    set -gx VISUAL nvim

    # PATHS
    set -gx PATH /Users/napo/bin /Users/napo/.local/bin /Users/napo/.cargo/bin $PATH
    set -gx PATH $PATH /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin

    neofetch
end

# Use personal aliases
if test -e "$HOME/.config/fish/path.fish"
    source ~/.config/fish/path.fish
end

if test -e "$HOME/.config/fish/aliases.fish"
    source ~/.config/fish/aliases.fish
end

if test -e "$HOME/.config/fish/chpwd.fish"
    source ~/.config/fish/chpwd.fish
end

if test -e "$HOME/.config/fish/functions.fish"
    source ~/.config/fish/functions.fish
end

# for things not checked into git.
if test -e "$HOME/.extra.fish"
    source ~/.extra.fish
end

# Prefer GB English and use UTF-8
set -x LC_ALL en_GB.UTF-8
set -x LANG en_GB

set -g theme_nerd_fonts yes
set -g theme_show_exit_status yes

# Allow 256 colors in iTerm2 for pretty vim colors
#set -gx TERM xterm-256color
set -gx CLICOLOR 1

# better ls colors
eval (gdircolors --c-shell $HOME/dircolors)

# Remove fish greeting
set fish_greeting

# highlighting inside manpages and elsewhere
set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_mb \e'[01;31m' # begin blinking
set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_md \e'[01;38;5;74m' # begin bold
set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_me \e'[0m' # end mode
set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_se \e'[0m' # end standout-mode
set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_so \e'[38;5;246m' # begin standout-mode - info box
set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_ue \e'[0m' # end underline
set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_us \e'[04;38;5;146m' # begin underline

# jump config
status --is-interactive
and source (jump shell |psub)

# direnv config
eval (direnv hook fish)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with fish 3.0.0 - see https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5456.

The suggestion there is to add a reordering function to your startup:

```
function path-reordered -d "Echos the elements of $PATH, reordered such that custom paths precede standard system paths. This can be used to work around a fish 3.0.0 bug in which sub-shells fail to respect path ordering."
  set -l sys_paths

  for p in $PATH
      if string match -q -r '^/usr/|^/s?bin(/|$)' $p
          set -a sys_paths $p
      else
          echo $p
      end
  end

  for p in $sys_paths; echo $p; end
end
```

Then, in `config.fish`:

```
if status --is-login
     set PATH $HOME/.local/bin $PATH
     # etc.
else
     set PATH (path-reordered)
end
```